# How long does generated IDs by Google Drive API lasts / when should they be used?

Tags: google-drive-api, grpc, drive

I was unable to find information on the expiration date of Google Drive IDs in the Google Drive documentation. I need to understand how long I can rely on a generated ID that may not have been used for a specific amount of time.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/generateIds

I'm building an application that needs to find or create Google Drive folders as one of its steps. In my database, I'm storing some of the folder metadata, such as Google Drive ID, folder name, etc.

In a find/create flow, I currently check the database first to obtain the Google Drive ID and then verify with the API if that ID is valid or has been used. If not, I use the same ID to create a folder in the API. If I don't find anything, I call the API to generate an ID, save it in the database along with the folder metadata, and then call the API to create the folder.

The goal is to minimize API calls and build code that can fail at any time but can also be retried as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Generated Google Drive IDs are unique identifiers for each file and folder so it won’t expire. Folder or file IDs will still be the same even if you change the name of the file or folder.

Reference:
[**File ID**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-files)